# linking shiny actionButton and rhandsontable

Tags: r, shiny

I'm having trouble linking a shiny action button and a `rhandsontable` table that is being displayed by `renderRHandsontable`. When the `actionButton` is clicked, a new row should be added to the table and that change should automatically re-render the table with the new data.

My current code adds the row to a global table, but `rhandsontable` doesn't automatically re-render the UI table. You have to manually refresh the page in order to see the change. Is there a way to trigger `renderRHandsontable` from within a shiny event handler?

Here's the basic situation:

global.R:

```
globalData <- new.env()
globalData$table <- data.frame(a = 1:10, b = 10:1)
```

server.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

    observeEvent(input$addRow, {
        newRow <- data.frame("a" = 99, "b" = 99)
        globalData$table <<- rbind(globalData$table, newRow)
        # need to trigger a table refresh here ?
    })

    output$table <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(globalData$table, rowHeaders = NULL)
    })

})
```

ui.R:

```
library(shiny)
library(rhandsontable)

shinyUI(fluidPage(

    rHandsontableOutput("table"),
    actionButton("addRow", "Add")

))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a reproducible example please

Comment: @Rachel did you manage to solve this?

Comment: Yes I did actually. Binding the rhandsontable object in an EventReative solved the problem.